# Some file crunching failed, mergeDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android

This error occurred today after I updated Android Studio from 2.2 to 2.3 , and run app to my phone.  Everything was OK last Friday. This Monday gift ruined my all day.
Gradle setting is "Use local gradle distribution", version 3.3 .

log info as below, because it's too long and all of them are similar, I just copied some segments:

```
Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
AAPT: \\?\C:\Users\任\.android\build-cache\41cfce3bb6e2ca4b269727fe91725c24a067ec68\output\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT: \\?\C:\Users\任\.android\build-cache\41cfce3bb6e2ca4b269727fe91725c24a067ec68\output\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_ic_star_half_black_48dp.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT: \\?\C:\Users\任\.android\build-cache\41cfce3bb6e2ca4b269727fe91725c24a067ec68\output\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT: \\?\C:\Users\任\.android\build-cache\41cfce3bb6e2ca4b269727fe91725c24a067ec68\output\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file

AAPT err(Facade for 925134644) : No Delegate set : lost message:\\?\C:\Users\任\.android\build-cache\41cfce3bb6e2ca4b269727fe91725c24a067ec68\output\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_star_half_black_48dp.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 925134644) : No Delegate set : lost message:\\?\C:\Users\任\.android\build-cache\41cfce3bb6e2ca4b269727fe91725c24a067ec68\output\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
```

build.gradle as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
        compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    }
}
```

According to advice from other questions, although some answers are just too outdated, still I have tried following ways, unfortunately, none of them saved me:
1.  remove all .9.png files from my project.
2.  check all png files are real PNG.
3.  insert following settings to build.gradle :

```
aaptOptions {  
    cruncherEnabled = false  
}
```

4.  check project file path, not reaching 255 characters (Windows 10).
5.  clear gradle caches.
6.  Invalidate caches and restart.
7.  clean project.

I think log info leads me to files auto-generated by Android Studio. Trying to search error .png files, none of them exists in my project.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I always have this problem when I have malformed drawables. So if you are copying drawables, make sure that can be opened with media software installed on your computer.

Comment: @FarazAhmed thanks for your reply, but I do mentioned at 2nd items saying that I have checked this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

problem solved. The solution is [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=236304).

Related data as below:
1. According to release notes of Android Studio version 2.3, build cache is enabled by default.
2. so we should disable this setting. Here is official guide, Android Studio/User Guide/build-cache(link  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache.html).
3. go to gradle.properties file, and disable build cache.

```
// To re-enable the build cache, either delete the following
// line or set the property to 'true'.
android.enableBuildCache=false
```

the other way is to modify build cache dir by adding

```
# first line can be skipped because true is the default value by 2.3
android.enableBuildCache=true
android.buildCacheDir =c:\\temp\\
```

Comment: Awsome! Changing the cache directory worked to me! I think that's the best solution.

Comment: For novice user like me: you are adding this in gradle.properties file.

Comment: @green0range   Yes, as mentioned at 3rd step. I'm not sure if this problem still exists, just try it if you are stuck with the same log infos.

Comment: @Longer Ah. Did not see that... I guess I was blind.

Answer (score 0):

It's causing this error because in your drawable you must have change the extension to .png from other format.I would recommend that to change the extension use MS paint or Other image editing application like Gimp.

Comment: I have checked this by select all drawable files and right click to see their properties, it says Types are png files.